Postman error "unsupported_grant_type"
I'm trying to connect to a developer edition of Salesforce via Postman,
but I keep getting the "unsupported_grant_type" error.
Does anyone know how to fix it?


This error is observed since the grant type key specified must be in lower case - grant_type
Also , all the keys need to be in lower case.
Just replace all keys with lower case as shown in below link.
More info can be found here

Thanks, it worked!

Great , you can accept the answer as stated in this article. It will help someone in the future.

The username-password flow is generally not recommended (it's barely ok to use for prototyping in sandboxes... barely).
I believe that the web-server flow (i.e. the authorization code flow with pkce) is the default, and I think all other flows need to be explicitly enabled in the connected app.
You'll also want to use the authorization tab in postman so it can take care of things like adding the code (for the pkce part of the flow) and handling the intermediate call (because you start by hitting the token endpoint, salesforce responds with a challenge, then you have to hit the endpoint again before finally getting the access token).

Type: OAuth 2.0
Grant Type: Authorization Code (with pkce)
Callback Url: Whatever your connected app was set up with
Auth Url: https://<hostname>/services/oauth2/authorize
Token Url: https://<hostname>/services/oauth2/token
Client Id/Client Secret are all from your connected app
Scroll to the bottom and hit the "Get new Access Token" button
Put your credentials into the window that pops up

<hostname> is going to be something like login.salesforce.com or my-custom-domain.my.salesforce.com, or company--QA.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
